# On convergence of problematic series.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Determine if the following series is converges or not

$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\ln^{\ln(\ln n)} (n)}$$

Comment: Hint: $ (\log \log n)^2 \leq \log n$ for large $n$.

Comment: Also, $\log^{\log\log n}(n)=e^{(\log\log n)^2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $$\ln\left(\frac{1}{\ln^{\ln(\ln n)}(n)}\right)=\ln1-\ln(\ln^{\ln(\ln n)}(n))=-\ln(\ln n)\ln(\ln n)=-\left[\ln(\ln n)\right]^2$$
Therefore
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{1}{\ln^{\ln(\ln n)}(n)}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty e^{\ln\left(\frac{1}{\ln^{\ln(\ln n)}(n)}\right)}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty e^{-\left[\ln(\ln n)\right]^2}$$
It's not too hard to show that $\left[\ln(\ln n)\right]^2<\ln n$ for sufficiently large $n$. Therefore, for sufficiently large $n$, we have $e^{-\left[\ln(\ln n)\right]^2}>e^{-\ln n}=\frac{1}{n}$, so the series diverges (by comparison with the harmonic series).

Answer (score 2):

Not too hard seeing that the following limit is infinite:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n^1\times\frac{1}{\ln^{\ln(\ln n)}(n)}=+\infty$$ So according to a result of the Comparison Test, the series diverges.

Comment: Nice and quick approach! +1

Comment: + I agree with Amzoti!

Answer (score 1):

Do it by comparison with $\sum_a^\infty \frac{1}{n}$. We want to show that ultimately, $(\ln n)^{\ln\ln n}\lt n$. Equivalently, we want to show that ultimately, $(\ln\ln n)^2\lt \ln n$.

This can be done in various ways, like L'Hospital's Rule.

Or else we can let $\ln\ln n=t$. So we want to show that for $t$ large, we have $t^2\lt e^t$. This is easy, for positive $t$, by the power series expansion, $e^t\gt \frac{t^3}{3!}$.